# How to build for tier 3 target not included in `rustup target list`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I would like to build my Rust library for the `aarch64-apple-ios-sim` target. This target is considered a [Tier 3 target](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html) and does not appear in my list of available targets when I run `rustup target list` on either of the latest stable or nightly toolchains. I have tried running `rustup target add aarch64-apple-ios-sim` on the off chance that it's just a "hidden" target or something, but that did not work. What is the correct way to install a tier 3 target?

Comment: don't think it's currently available try `aarch64-apple-ios` should work to for `aarch64-apple-ios-sim`

Comment: @Stargateur I'm able to install `aarch64-apple-ios`, but libraries build with this target cannot be linked to iOS apps built for the simulator on M1 Macs.

Comment: You have to get the source and cross-compile it yourself -- there aren't any offical builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

- `rustup +nightly component add rust-src`
- `cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target aarch64-apple-ios-sim`

Here you can find more info: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support/aarch64-apple-ios-sim.html#building-rust-programs